# Key value coding failure

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-coding

So I have some json in a file like so

```
{
"address": {
    "home": {
        "street": "A Street"
    }
}
```

}

I pull out the json string like so

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I want to change a value on the fly, using a key path, so I need to make a deep mutable copy of the structure. So I am doing it like so

```
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:json];
json = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Using breakpoints I can see the json and it all looks fine.  However, I get a crash on this line

```
[json setValue:@"Different Street" forKeyPath:@"address.home.street"];
```

The compiler suggested there isn't a key at this key path that conforms to key-value coding.

Annoyingly, this line works fine and returns the street string

```
id value = [json valueForKeyPath:@"address.home.street"];
```

Why can't I set a value like this?

---

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSDictionaryI 0x1741bb580> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key pan.'

Comment: Please paste exactly what the compiler / crash log says.

Comment: What makes you think that the dict is mutable? Just a simple `NSLog(@"%@", [json class]);` would reveal => `__NSDictionaryI`

Comment: That would return an error like this  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Comment: But I am not getting that error

Comment: @robdashnash Do not confuse `setObject:forKey:` with `setValue:forKey:` (one is a method of `NSMutableDictionary` while the other of `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol) ... They produce different errors. The dictionary is immutable, that is the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NSJSONReadingMutableContainers when reading your JSON.  By default your containers are read in as immutable containers.

`id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments|NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];`